How to stop rsyslog from creating weird folders when vCenter logs come in?
I have installed rsyslog on a Fedora 40 server and would like to use this server as a log server in our network.
This was my original rsyslog template configuration (of course I also enabled TCP and UDP modules): 
$template PerHostLog,"/var/log/syslog/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"
if $fromhost-ip startswith '10.' then -?PerHostLog
& STOP
After that I enabled and linked the log server on our vCenter 8 to test whether the forwarding of the logs works. The logs are saved at the configured location (our vcenter host is called srv05tff-vcenter-10) on the log server, but many other folders (which I assume are coming from vCenter too, since it's the only host sending logs currently) are also created:
root@srv76tff-log-10:/var/log/syslog# ll
drwx------. 2 root root    47  3. Okt 11:53 al
drwx------. 2 root root    24  3. Okt 12:24 amples
drwx------. 2 root root    30  3. Okt 13:11 ations
drwx------. 2 root root    24  3. Okt 12:03 ax
**drwx------. 2 root root  4096  3. Okt 12:24 srv05tff-vcenter-01** # the one i want
drwx------. 2 root root    26  3. Okt 12:03 Filter
drwx------. 2 root root    24  3. Okt 12:03 in
drwx------. 2 root root    43  3. Okt 13:11 l
drwx------. 2 root root    26  3. Okt 13:05 les
drwx------. 2 root root    46  3. Okt 12:50 max
drwx------. 2 root root    24  3. Okt 12:03 mean
drwx------. 2 root root    25  3. Okt 12:24 min
drwx------. 2 root root    24  3. Okt 12:14 n
drwx------. 2 root root    19  3. Okt 11:23 nDetails
drwx------. 2 root root    30  3. Okt 13:16 ns
drwx------. 2 root root    30  3. Okt 11:22 ons
drwx------. 2 root root    30  3. Okt 11:58 Operations
drwx------. 2 root root    70  3. Okt 13:31 otal
drwx------. 2 root root    97  3. Okt 14:07 tal
drwx------. 2 root root    22  3. Okt 12:19 tenance
drwx------. 2 root root    30  3. Okt 12:09 tion
drwx------. 2 root root    24  3. Okt 11:43 total
drwx------. 2 root root    23  3. Okt 13:26 ts
drwx------. 2 root root    26  3. Okt 14:07 umSamples
I played around with the configuration of the template to have rsyslog convert any special characters that might be interfering, and tried options such as :clean, :?-unknown:clean and :escape-cc, but none of it helped.
I currently have the following configuration, which does not help either:
$template PerHostLog,"/var/log/syslog/%HOSTNAME:clean%/%PROGRAMNAME:replace:([()\\])=_:clean%.log"
if $fromhost-ip startswith '10.' then -?PerHostLog
& STOP
Does anyone know why these folders keep flooding my rsyslog location?

Perhaps the input logs you are receiving contain the newline character, which is normally only used at the end of a log item. Look at the logged entries to see if they seem to end prematurely. Save all the logs to one file and look at them to see if they are all structured correctly, especially the header.

Another possibility is that the logs are sent in a different format than rsyslog expects. Please share your full TCP/UDP reception as well as some example log entries.
